# AWS bandwidth calculation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am running a website in cPanel server. The website use average 100G bandwidth per month. I wish to move my website to AWS, so to understand about the cost I have used AWS calculator. The caluclator asking me to add some values like

Data Transfer Out:

Data Transfer In:

Public IP/Elastic IP Data Transfer:

Can somebody explain me about these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data transfer in is the data sent to your server. It's probably a small fraction of total traffic unless you use FTP.

Data transfer out is the data sent to your users. It's usually the bulk of the data.

Ignore elastic IP in this context.

I did a quick calculation. 10GB in (free), 90GB out, is $6.75 per month in the us-east region. I then added a t2.large (which may be too big or too small), a t2.small RDS database, and some disk, come to around $90/month. If you pay up front it can be cheaper, if you don't need RDS it's cheaper, if you can use a smaller instance (depends on your use) it can be cheaper. [Pricing example here](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#r=IAD&key=calc-BC49BFC7-BAA5-4C5D-ABA1-1132C89103D2).

**Update**
I've included a one year no upfront reserved instances. That means you pay nothing up front, but you must continue to pay for the instance for 12 months. You can choose partial upfront or full upfront to get a bigger discount. That's why "no upfront" gives you a low monthly cost, but look in the pricing tab for the up front price.

I would suggest you go with on-demand instances to start with, as they're paid by the hour with no commitment. Once you're happy with your instance size you could go for a reserved instance. You use CloudWatch to look at resource usage - CPU, network, etc, and memory once you [install the right script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) (the hypervisor has no idea what the OS is doing with the RAM).

More on reserved instances [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/).

Comment: Thank you, Tim. Could you please let me know what is 1 Yr no upfront reserved and 1 Yr all upfront reserved. When I am select 1 Yr all upfront and the monthly cost become 0$

Comment: See update above.